# How to make update-grub recognize zfs datasets as root in /etc/fstab and add minimal set of zfs options?

Tags: grub2, fstab, grub-efi, zfs

I'm having trouble to find out how to make `update-grub` of `grub-efi` 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1 recognize the specification of a ZFS dataset as root device in `/etc/fstab` and conditionally add a minimal set of ZFS options *without* writing code (in `/etc/grub.d/10_*` or `/etc/default/grub`).

Currently my setup is that `/` is on ZFS pool `rpool2/ROOT/ubuntu-trusty-1`, `/boot/` is on an ext4 partition, booting is done with EFI (all entries are in `/etc/fstab`), disk has a GPT. This requires `root=ZFS=rpool2/ROOT/ubuntu-2 boot=zfs bootfs=rpool2/ROOT/ubuntu-2 rpool=rpool2` rather than `root=/dev/sda5` only as arguments for the `linux` directive in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and that being added automatically is my goal.

AFAIK the solution should be independent from setting up other systems in multiboot. I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 amd64. I installed `ubuntu-zfs` 0.6.3 and `zfs-initramfs` from `ppa:zfs-native/stable`.

**Some more details**: The issue has come up in some issue reports on github (e.g. https://github.com/zfsonlinux/grub/issues/10). The research result for me is that one needs a "zfs aware" grub version which needs to be from source (because the PPA `ppa:zfs-native/grub` supports until 13.04 only, missing support for 14.04 addressed in https://github.com/zfsonlinux/grub/issues/12). The current version for building from source is errornous, e.g. `LANG=C apt-get source --build grub-efi` fails due to a conflict with `libzfs-dev` which reaches beyond my understanding, details:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'grub2' as source package instead of 'grub-efi'
NOTICE: 'grub2' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
git://anonscm.debian.org/pkg-grub/grub.git -b experimental
Skipping already downloaded file 'grub2_2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.dsc'
Skipping already downloaded file 'grub2_2.02~beta2.orig.tar.xz'
Skipping already downloaded file 'grub2_2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.debian.tar.gz'
Need to get 0 B of source archives.
Skipping unpack of already unpacked source in grub2-2.02~beta2
dpkg-buildpackage: source package grub2
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution trusty
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Colin Watson <cjwatson@ubuntu.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build grub2-2.02~beta2
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Build conflicts: libzfs-dev libnvpair-dev
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
Build command 'cd grub2-2.02~beta2 && dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc' failed.
E: Child process failed
```

i.e. I can't estimate how deeply reaching this conflict is and whether I oversaw one of the numberous issue reports on github addressing the issue and/or referencing a fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a patch available at https://code.launchpad.net/~krichter722/+junk/grub2_zfs_support_improvement. As long as it isn't integrated into the package (if it isn't refused). It should be possible to get the issue fixed with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep grub-efi # after you set up sources in apt repositories
bzr branch lp:~krichter722/+junk/grub2_zfs_support_improvement
cd grub2_zfs_support_improvement
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-platform=efi
make
sudo make install
sudo mv /etc/grub.d/10_linux /etc/grub.d/10_linux.bk
sudo cp 10_linux /etc/grub.d/
```

and then you can run `sudo update-grub` as usual (an experimental version of `grub` will be installed!).